# wrong reading in uart communication in python

Tags: python, uart

I am using serial library of python for uart communication. The communication is between fpga and python 3. I am sending constant values, which are 104 108 112 115 120 as 16 bit(LSB byte is 0), from fpga to python which is run on windows 10. However,sometimes python is reading data as 104000, 108000, 112000, 115000 and 120000. It looks like python read the one byte which is belong to next comming data and it is combining them. Thus, the value is wrong.
Could someone help me in order to find the problem? I have checked the each data from fpga side and it is working without problem.
The code is given below;

```
import random
from itertools import count
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
#from tkinter import *
import serial
import time

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
fig = plt.figure()

ser=serial.Serial()
ser.port = 'COM4'
ser.baudrate = 57600
ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE
ser.timeout = 1
ser.open()

#root=Tk()
a_vals = []
b_vals = []
c_vals = []
q_vals = []
d_vals = []
x_vals = []

index = count()

def animate(i):

 package = bytearray()
 package.append(0x7F)
 package.append(0x7F)
 send_data = ser.write(package)
 Ia_low1 = ser.read(1)
 Ia_high1 = ser.read(1)
 Ib_low1 = ser.read(1)
 Ib_high1 = ser.read(1)
 Ic_low1 = ser.read(1)
 Ic_high1 = ser.read(1)
 Iq_low1 = ser.read(1)
 Iq_high1 = ser.read(1)
 Id_low1 = ser.read(1)
 Id_high1 = ser.read(1)

 Ia_low = ord(Ia_low1)
 Ia_high = ord(Ia_high1)
 Ib_low = ord(Ib_low1)
 Ib_high = ord(Ib_high1)
 Ic_low = ord(Ic_low1)
 Ic_high = ord(Ic_high1)
 Iq_low = ord(Iq_low1)
 Iq_high = ord(Iq_high1)
 Id_low = ord(Id_low1)
 Id_high = ord(Id_high1)
 Ia = Ia_high*1000 + Ia_low
 Ib = Ib_high*1000 + Ib_low
 Ic = Ic_high*1000 + Ic_low
 Iq = Iq_high*1000 + Iq_low
 Id = Id_high*1000 + Id_low
 time.sleep (0.1)

 a_vals.append(Ia)
 b_vals.append(Ib)
 c_vals.append(Ic)
 q_vals.append(Iq)
 d_vals.append(Id)
 x_vals.append(random.randint(0, 100))

 print ("Ia =", Ia)
 print ("Ib =", Ib)
 print ("Ic =", Ic)

 ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
 ax1.cla()
 ax1.plot(x_vals, a_vals, label='Ia')
 ax1.plot(x_vals, b_vals, label='Ib')
 ax1.plot(x_vals, c_vals, label='Ic')
 ax1.set_title('Ia, Ib, Ic illustration window')
 ax1.set_xlabel('sample')
 ax1.set_ylabel('current')
 ax1.legend()

 ax2 = plt.subplot(122)
 ax2.cla()
 ax2.plot(x_vals, q_vals, label='Iq')
 ax2.plot(x_vals, d_vals, label='Id')
 ax2.set_title('Iq, Id illustration window')
 ax2.set_xlabel('sample')
 ax2.set_ylabel('current')
 ax2.legend()

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval = 200)


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: In addition, I have observed that, read() command is not waitng for data. So python is closing the communcation, but data sending is going on. After that, when communication is starting again, python is starting data read at any low bit. Thus, this condition causes wrong reading. The new problem is, **How can I grantee that python wait reading data?**

Comment: Colud anyone help or give any clue?